# Inject typed presenter cause error (moxy)

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, moxy

My presenter is:

```
@InjectViewState
    class SearchPresenter<T>(val network: Network) : BasePresenter<SearchView<T>>() {
    //pass
    }
```

T - data clas to be passed. Т might be on of 5 types of data class не with no mutual parents

Data class type is know to fragment who injects presenter

How I work with presenter from one of fragments:

```
class SearchNewsFragment : SearchBaseFragment(), NewsView<NewsShortEntity> {

    @InjectPresenter
    lateinit var presenter: SearchPresenter<NewsShortEntity>

  @ProvidePresenter
    fun provideSearchPresenter(): SearchPresenter<NewsShortEntity> {
        return SearchPresenter(network)
    }
```

View:

```
interface NewsView<T> : SearchView<T> {
//pass
}
```

What I receive:

> error: You can not use @InjectPresenter in classes that are not View,
>   which is typified target Presenter public
>   SearchPresenter
>   presenter;

How to win this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change

```
class SearchPresenter<T>(val network: Network) : BasePresenter<SearchView<T>>()
```

to

```
class SearchPresenter<T>(val network: Network) : BasePresenter<NewsView<T>>()
```